# Vimdiff bring next diff at top or in the centre

Tags: vim, vimdiff

While viewing diff of two files using vimdiff, when I do `]c` to go to the next diff, the beginning of that next diff appears at the last line. Due to this, I have to scroll up few lines up to view the whole diff. Currently i do `zt` to take it to the top.

Is there any command / mapping that i can use to make the next diff appear at the top or at the centre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nnoremap ]c j]cztk
```

That seems to do the trick

It simply do the two commands you usually pair up.
The `k` at the end goes up one line, because it seems that the `zt` goes up too far.
And thus, the `j` is necessary so that vim actually goes to the next diff